# CMake: how to embed build configuration (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel,...) into binary?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm using Cmake's `configure_file()` function to generate a header that I include into my project.
This way, I can for example store into the resulting binary the git commit hash of the code beeing compiled.

Now I'm trying to make my program aware of the compilation configuration which has been used: `Debug`, `Release`, `MinSizeRel` or `RelWithDebInfo`.

The toolchain used is VisualStudio, therefore all configurations are generated by CMake at the same time. So for example, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is alays set to `Release`.

What is the common way to make the program built aware of the the build mode used ?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a file, containing build type-specific values, using `file(GENERATE)` command. This command expands generator expressions.

For example, the call

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_$<CONFIG>
  CONTENT "Build type: $<CONFIG>")
```

at the end of configuration will create `build_Debug` file with content `Build type: Debug`, `build_Release` file with content `Build type: Release` and so on.

Resulted files could be used in custom commands:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some_file_$<CONFIG> 
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_$<CONFIG>
  COMMAND do-something-with build_$<CONFIG>
)
```

---

Note, that `file(GENERATE)` doesn't expand variables. So if you want to combine in the resulted file both variables values and generator expressions, then you need to "pipe" `configure_file` with `file(GENERATE)`.

my_file.in:

```
var: @MY_VAR@
build type: $<CONFIG>
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Creates intermediate file with expanded variables.
configure_file(my_file.in my_file_intermediate @ONLY)
# Expands generator expressions in the intermediate file and creates "final" files
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_file_$<CONFIG>
  INPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_file_intermediate)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CMake generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) with the `add_compile_definitions` command (or any other command which accepts generator expressions).

Like this: `add_compile_definitions(CONFIG_TYPE="$<CONFIG>")`. Then use the `CONFIG_TYPE` macro in your C++ code.

Comment: Don't use directory commands like `add_compile_definitions` in new code. Prefer their target-specific variants like `target_compile_definitions`.

Comment: Imho this approach is preferrable to the one Tsyvarev presented, and I would have upvoted, if not for the fact that you're recommending a solution that adds the info at a scope that is much too broad: Any target generated after this command in the same `CMakeLists.txt` or in a subdirectory will see this preprocessor definitions making it all to easy to cause undesired effects and make refactoring of the project harder. In fact limiting the define to the target may be broader than necessary; adding it at source file level would be optimal.

Comment: @fabian `add_compile_definitions` is just a way to add things without knowing what project structure OP has. The real thing in this answer is a generator expression. How it would be used, is up to the user. I presented just one way.

Comment: @ixSci - the issue is that you present the _worst_ way in terms of how likely it is to cause surprising failures.

Comment: @fabian - you're actually slightly off about which set of targets `add_compile_definitions` affects. It's _all_ targets in the _same_ directory, including those that came before the command, and in subdirectories added _after_ the command, but not before. Also, this is why "Nothing is wrong with `add_compile_definitions`" is _factually incorrect_.

Comment: @ixSci If someone considers your solution, they'll likely just copy&paste your snippet into their own project. They should be aware of the drawbacks of using this exact snippet without modifying it. This is why imho answers should contain solutions using best practice or at least explain the drawbacks of the approach. Your answer not doing this is the reason for my downvote.

Comment: @fabian no I _shouldn't_. I don't believe in complete answers for brainless people who can't and won't check what they are doing. I know about this crusade against the global commands but I never supported it. I've been using CMake for 12 years and _never_ have a single problem with global functions. You just use the right tool for the right job, that's all. `add_compile_definitions` isn't dangerous enough to list drawbacks in the answer. That's not `goto` or `volatile` from C or C++ to put a disclaimer.

Comment: @ixSci: "That's not `goto` or `volatile` from C or C++ to put a disclaimer." - But you got more downvotes than my answers with `volatile`:) Actually, I don't agree with that downvotes too. There are complex projects with many targets and complex dependencies between them. In that projects target-oriented functions could be preferred. But there are also complex projects with a "plain" structure, where non-target-oriented functions will reduce complexity. "You just use the right tool for the right job, that's all" - Exactly.